# Validating Date Field In Flutter with Boolean Data

Tags: validation, drop-down-menu, dart, flutter

I'm trying to validate a date field in Flutter but, I keep getting this error:

The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 6785): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

```html
  Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          RaisedButton(
                                            highlightElevation: 8,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                              selectedYear != null
                                                  ? selectedYear.toString()
                                                  : "Age Checker",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.orange),
                                            ),
                                            onPressed: _showPicker,
                                            
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            width: 120,
                                            child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                              animation: animation,
                                              builder: (context, child) => FormField(
                                                builder:
                                                    (FormFieldState state) {
                                                  return InputDecorator(
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  labelText:  'You Are '
                                                        "${animation.value.toStringAsFixed(0)}",
                                                  errorText:  state.hasError
                                                          ? state.errorText
                                                          : null,
                                                ),
                                                isEmpty: selectedYear == '',
                                                  );
                                                     },  validator: (selectedYear) => selectedYear ? null: 'rawr',
                                                 
                                              ),
                                              
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
```

Here are my methods to help calculate age and validator to validate the age.

```
 void calculateAge() {
setState(() {
  age = (2018 - selectedYear).toDouble();

  animation = Tween<double>(begin: animation.value, end: age).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn, parent: animationController));

  animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
});
print(age);

if (age < 21){
  ageChecker();
} else{
}
```

}

bool isValidDob(String dob) {
  if (dob.isEmpty) return true;

}

I want to confirm the user is over 21 prior to moving on to the next screen. Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are calling this function?

```
bool isValidDob(String dob) { 
 if (dob.isEmpty) return true;
}
```

I think this function is causing the error, try changing it to the following

```
 bool isValidDob(String dob) { 
     if (dob.isEmpty){
      return true;
      }
     else{
       return false
       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This looks more like a comment, if your reputation level doesn't allow you to comment, make sure to at least provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Based on these incomplete snippets I think the problematic line is

`validator: (selectedYear) => selectedYear ? null: 'rawr'`
because the type of `selectedYear` is not specified and cannot be inferred. If you change it like

`validator: (int selectedYear) => selectedYear ? null: 'rawr'`
then analyzer will give an error for using a non-bool type in a condition. Also you can turn on `unrelated_type_equality_checks` analyzer option which will warn you for `selectedYear == ''` because you compare a string and a dynamic.

The fix is easy, `validator: (int selectedYear) => selectedYear >= 21 ? null: 'rawr'`

You can also get the same error for booleans too since in dart any variable can be null.